# The title of an English-spoken apocalyptic movie which features a large circuit of criminal-related trade in virtual reality experiences (pre 2000s)

Tags: identify-this-movie

I would like to ask if this can make anybody guess the title of a movie which was presumably published before the year 2000.

The elements which I think to remember about it, are as follows:

- English-spoken.
- Apocalyptic: the depicted world is quite miserable, crime is abundant.
- Many people have become addicted to virtual reality tapes/videos/CDs, such as porn imagery, which they can play through their digital glasses (appliances much like today's existing virtual reality glasses). In reality (such as depicted in the movie of course), those people are lying in destroyed or filthy buildings, which seems rather analogue to poor heroine addicts.
- It is almost as if the ream world does no longer entail the clean and soothing, or desirable places, products and/or situations which are depicted on the virtual reality tapes. Hence the imagery is a psychological escape from reality, for the addicts depicted.
- As the virtual tapes are trafficked, the illegal use of fire-arms is abundant.
- I deem to remember a strong depicted police force, much like a riot police; depicted quite mechanically and robotic.
- I guess there was a scene in a sort of rock/metal music bar/club, although I could be mistaken. This scene was not at the end of the movie. The scene might have ended in a shoot-out.
- I guess the final scene of the movie is a movie shot which zooms out progressively, showing massive chaos. I presume that the police force was also present there; although perhaps overtaken by the people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

["Strange Days" (1995)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114558/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

The movie can be watched here (crap quality):

Some of the details do not fit perfectly (no robotic police officers, for example), but the basic premise is similar, and at the end of the movie there is an outdoor rock concert, huge crowd, showdown between the good guys and bad guys, this causes chaos, rioting, and police officers are involved. This part starts ca. at 1:54:55 in the movie above (at 1:55:00 you can see people throwing rocks at police officers in riot gear). Also, earlier in the movie, there are scenes set in a rock/night club (starts ca. at 0:33:50, for example).

Plot on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Days_(film)):

> In the last two days of 1999, **Los Angeles has become a dangerous war
>   zone**. As a group of criminals rob a Chinese restaurant, **the event is
>   recorded by a robber wearing a SQUID, an illegal electronic device
>   that records events directly from the wearer's cerebral cortex, and
>   when played back through a MiniDisc-like device, allows a user to
>   experience the recorder's memories and physical sensations**. Lenny
>   Nero, a former LAPD officer turned **black marketeer of SQUID
>   recordings**, agrees to buy the robbery clip from his main supplier,
>   Tick.

Comment: Thanks @casspir. You have made a correct, and educated guess. I saw this movie as part of free movie screening series with corresponding discussion opportunities after the screenings, which took place at "Institut für Kunstgeschichte" at the "LMU" University in Munich; it must have been around 2011 or so (although I'll might be a few years off). I encountered or reinforced many interesting thoughts during these series.

Comment: You're welcome. If you live in Germany, you can pick it up on blu-ray cheaply, a very good quality 20th anniversary edition exists.